# How can i get OnTriggerEnter angle in Unity ? c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a basketball game where I put collider to The hoop and checked "is trigger" so I can detect when the ball passes throught it. But i want this to happen only when ball passes through it from above, not beneath. How can I solve it ?

Comment: The hit point will tell you where it hit the collider. You could tell if it’s below or above.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution to this problem is to use `Vector3.Dot`. This method works in such a way that when the two angles are equal, it returns the value of 1, when it is perpendicular, it returns the value of 0, and when it is opposite, it shows the value of -1, the rest is between these numbers. Now you only need to measure the dot axis of the ball velocity with the downward direction. Numbers greater than zero definitely indicate acceleration from top to bottom.

```cs
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Basket)
    {
        if (Vector3.Dot(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity, Vector3.down) > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Goal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: KiynL, Thanks it helped a lot